# Can I get back to synchronous code after an async function is finished?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

An example of an async function:

```
async function getJSONA(callback){

    let json = await request.get(url, (req, res, html) => {
        callback = html
    });

    return callback;
}

getJSONAsync().then((res) => {
    fs.writeFileSync(`page.html`, res)
    console.log(1)
})
```

Works great, at the end you get the "1". Now, let's say after the `.then` function I want to write a console.log, like this

```
getJSONAsync().then((res) => {
    fs.writeFileSync(`page.html`, res)
    console.log(1)
})

console.log(2)
```

Obviously, 2 will be logged sooner than 1. And yes, I can further write asynchronous constructions to continue the flow. But that complicates the code and makes it less readable, at least for me. So is there a way to, after execution of the async part, get back to normal, synchronous code like I mentioned above?

Comment: write synchronous code inside a function and call that function inside `.then`

Comment: That's honestly a pretty good way of doing it. Thanks.

Comment: This article helped me with Promises (in case you still have confusion.)
https://medium.com/@bluepnume/learn-about-promises-before-you-start-using-async-await-eb148164a9c8

Comment: Is `getJSONA` supposed to be `getJSONAsync`?

Comment: Your question makes no sense. By definition, asynchronous functions don't block the rest of the code from running, that's the whole point.

Answer (score 0):

In order to accomplish the sequencing you're looking for, you're going to need to use additional asynchronous constructions. Those can get very complicated but you've got a couple options:

1. *Chain promises:*

   You are waiting on the `Promise` returned by `getJSONAsync` to resolve before printing `1` by calling the method `Promise#then`, which also returns another `Promise` that you can use to do further sequencing. That'd look something like this:

   ```
   getJSONAsync().then((res) => {
     fs.writeFileSync(`page.html`, res)
     console.log(1)
   }).then(() => {
     console.log(2)
   })
   ```
2. *Wrap with another `async` function:*

   Alternatively, you can wrap the entire thing with an async function. If you're already in an async function you won't need to do any wrapping, but otherwise in order to use `await` you'll need to introduce another async function which you can then call.

   ```
   async function getAndWriteJSON() {
     const res = await getJSONAsync();
     fs.writeFileSync(`page.html`, res)
     console.log(1);
     console.log(2);
   }
   getAndWriteJSON();
   ```